# How to change an already registered dialog in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor

I'm trying to write a plugin, that adds an additional tab (page) to the image dialog. I don't want to change the dialog's source itself, but enhance it with the plugin.

I searched the docs and the forum for quite some time now, and I now know that I can call "addPage" on the dialogs object to add another tab. I also understand how the contents object must look like.
But I failed in finding the way how to get the dialog object of an already existing dialog.

I tried a

```
var ImageDialog = new CKEDITOR.dialog( editor, 'image' );
```

within the plugin's init method, but that caused an JS error "R is not a function"...

Can somebody help me out here, please?

Thanks in advance,
Marc

Comment: whats the object editor?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can find that code in the ["API dialog" sample](http://nightly.ckeditor.com/6480/_samples/api_dialog.html)

Comment: @VitoShadow then open the /Samples in your local install and search for the "API dialog" or something similar in case they rename it in the future.

Comment: Perhaps that was the case 3 years ago, but not anymore. You should always post code in your solutions. Links don't last.

Comment: this is updated link:http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor_4.3_beta/samples/plugins/dialog/dialog.html

Comment: also this is the sample code in github:https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/dialog/samples/dialog.html

Comment: None of the provided links currently work, except for the github example.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this link](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/master/plugins/dialog/samples/dialog.html) in one of the comments in Alfonso's answer, and it did the trick for me.

Since links go bad, especially after all these years, here is the code from the linked page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
Copyright (c) 2003-2022, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Using API to Customize Dialog Windows &mdash; CKEditor Sample</title>
    <script src="../../../ckeditor.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../samples/old/sample.css">
    <meta name="ckeditor-sample-name" content="Using the JavaScript API to customize dialog windows">
    <meta name="ckeditor-sample-group" content="Advanced Samples">
    <meta name="ckeditor-sample-description" content="Using the dialog windows API to customize dialog windows without changing the original editor code.">
    <meta name="description" content="Try the latest sample of CKEditor 4 and learn more about customizing your WYSIWYG editor with endless possibilities.">
    <style>

        .cke_button__mybutton_icon
        {
            display: none !important;
        }

        .cke_button__mybutton_label
        {
            display: inline !important;
        }

    </style>
    <script>

        CKEDITOR.on( 'instanceCreated', function( ev ){
            var editor = ev.editor;

            // Listen for the "pluginsLoaded" event, so we are sure that the
            // "dialog" plugin has been loaded and we are able to do our
            // customizations.
            editor.on( 'pluginsLoaded', function() {

                // If our custom dialog has not been registered, do that now.
                if ( !CKEDITOR.dialog.exists( 'myDialog' ) ) {
                    // We need to do the following trick to find out the dialog
                    // definition file URL path. In the real world, you would simply
                    // point to an absolute path directly, like "/mydir/mydialog.js".
                    var href = document.location.href.split( '/' );
                    href.pop();
                    href.push( 'assets/my_dialog.js' );
                    href = href.join( '/' );

                    // Finally, register the dialog.
                    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'myDialog', href );
                }

                // Register the command used to open the dialog.
                editor.addCommand( 'myDialogCmd', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'myDialog' ) );

                // Add the a custom toolbar buttons, which fires the above
                // command..
                editor.ui.add( 'MyButton', CKEDITOR.UI_BUTTON, {
                    label: 'My Dialog',
                    command: 'myDialogCmd'
                });
            });
        });

        // When opening a dialog, its "definition" is created for it, for
        // each editor instance. The "dialogDefinition" event is then
        // fired. We should use this event to make customizations to the
        // definition of existing dialogs.
        CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev ) {
            // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
            var dialogName = ev.data.name;
            var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

            // Check if the definition is from the dialog we're
            // interested on (the "Link" dialog).
            if ( dialogName == 'myDialog' && ev.editor.name == 'editor2' ) {
                // Get a reference to the "Link Info" tab.
                var infoTab = dialogDefinition.getContents( 'tab1' );

                // Add a new text field to the "tab1" tab page.
                infoTab.add( {
                    type: 'text',
                    label: 'My Custom Field',
                    id: 'customField',
                    'default': 'Sample!',
                    validate: function() {
                        if ( ( /\d/ ).test( this.getValue() ) )
                            return 'My Custom Field must not contain digits';
                    }
                });

                // Remove the "select1" field from the "tab1" tab.
                infoTab.remove( 'select1' );

                // Set the default value for "input1" field.
                var input1 = infoTab.get( 'input1' );
                input1[ 'default' ] = 'www.example.com';

                // Remove the "tab2" tab page.
                dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'tab2' );

                // Add a new tab to the "Link" dialog.
                dialogDefinition.addContents( {
                    id: 'customTab',
                    label: 'My Tab',
                    accessKey: 'M',
                    elements: [
                        {
                            id: 'myField1',
                            type: 'text',
                            label: 'My Text Field'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'myField2',
                            type: 'text',
                            label: 'Another Text Field'
                        }
                    ]
                });

                // Provide the focus handler to start initial focus in "customField" field.
                dialogDefinition.onFocus = function() {
                    var urlField = this.getContentElement( 'tab1', 'customField' );
                    urlField.select();
                };
            }
        });

        var config = {
            extraPlugins: 'dialog',
            toolbar: [ [ 'MyButton' ] ]
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="samples">
        <a href="../../../samples/old/index.html">CKEditor Samples</a> &raquo; Using CKEditor Dialog API
    </h1>
    <div class="warning deprecated">
        This sample is not maintained anymore. Check out the <a href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/index.html">brand new samples in CKEditor Examples</a>.
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        <p>
            This sample shows how to use the
            <a class="samples" href="https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_dialog.html">CKEditor Dialog API</a>
            to customize CKEditor dialog windows without changing the original editor code.
            The following customizations are being done in the example below:
        </p>
        <p>
            For details on how to create this setup check the source code of this sample page.
        </p>
    </div>
    <p>A custom dialog is added to the editors using the <code>pluginsLoaded</code> event, from an external <a target="_blank" href="assets/my_dialog.js">dialog definition file</a>:</p>
    <ol>
        <li><strong>Creating a custom dialog window</strong> &ndash; "My Dialog" dialog window opened with the "My Dialog" toolbar button.</li>
        <li><strong>Creating a custom button</strong> &ndash; Add button to open the dialog with "My Dialog" toolbar button.</li>
    </ol>
    <textarea cols="80" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="https://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
    <script>
        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with an CKEditor instance.
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', config );
    </script>
    <p>The below editor modify the dialog definition of the above added dialog using the <code>dialogDefinition</code> event:</p>
    <ol>
        <li><strong>Adding dialog tab</strong> &ndash; Add new tab "My Tab" to dialog window.</li>
        <li><strong>Removing a dialog window tab</strong> &ndash; Remove "Second Tab" page from the dialog window.</li>
        <li><strong>Adding dialog window fields</strong> &ndash; Add "My Custom Field" to the dialog window.</li>
        <li><strong>Removing dialog window field</strong> &ndash; Remove "Select Field" selection field from the dialog window.</li>
        <li><strong>Setting default values for dialog window fields</strong> &ndash; Set default value of "Text Field" text field. </li>
        <li><strong>Setup initial focus for dialog window</strong> &ndash; Put initial focus on "My Custom Field" text field. </li>
    </ol>
    <textarea cols="80" id="editor2" name="editor2" rows="10">&lt;p&gt;This is some &lt;strong&gt;sample text&lt;/strong&gt;. You are using &lt;a href="https://ckeditor.com/"&gt;CKEditor&lt;/a&gt;.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
    <script>

        // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with an CKEditor instance.
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor2', config );

    </script>
    <div id="footer">
        <hr>
        <p>
            CKEditor - The text editor for the Internet - <a class="samples" href="https://ckeditor.com/">https://ckeditor.com</a>
        </p>
        <p id="copy">
            Copyright &copy; 2003-2022, <a class="samples" href="https://cksource.com/">CKSource</a> Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
        </p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```